# SQL ERROR: Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, networking

I am getting following error while connecting to my local Sql Express.

```
An error has occurred. Details of the exception:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a conne
ction to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that
 the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Serve
r/Instance Specified)

Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
```

I am able to connect to Sql Server using Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to SQL Server using Management Studio installed on the same computer as SQL Server, or are you trying to connect remotely?  If you are trying to connect remotely, have you tried connecting locally?